# Add specified minutes to time using javascript

Tags: javascript

How we can add minutes to time, I want to add:

time = 21:36:13 and minutes 21:33

and want to get result 21:57:46

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript Date object stores time as the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 00:00:00 (in what should be UTC if the rest of your application is written properly). To add minutes and seconds, simply multiply te values to get the equivalent number of milliseconds, something like this: newDate = new Date(oldDate.getTime() + (((minutesToAdd * 60) + secondsToAdd) * 1000))

You should think about what you expect to happen during daylight saving time transitions. If the application is designed properly, the value in the Date object will be UTC, so the calculation above will always work correctly, but obviously the displayed value will be formatted as local time.

You may find a library such as [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to represent time? if you are using a native *Date* object, you can do something like this:

```
var addTime = function (baseDate, hours, minutes, seconds) {
    return new Date(baseDate.getTime() + hours*3600000 + minutes*60000 + seconds*1000);
}
```

This is basically creating a new Date object adding a series of hours, minutes and seconds to the base Date provided (all of it in milliseconds). Here's the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to work with Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date object with only taking interest in time. Here is your example:

```
function Foo()
{
   time = new Date();
   time.setHours(21);
   time.setMinutes(36);
   time.setSeconds(13);

   time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 21);
   time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 33);

   alert(time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds());
}
```

Hope it helps :D